# Capturar id en loop Java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

estoy creando una red social, en jsp y tengo una duda de como capturar el id de una publicacion que se esta mostrando en un forEach[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que se muestra esta en este loop

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero capturar la id en otro jsp donde esta el **82** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Para que otros puedan tratar de replicar tu problema, procura incluir tu código relevante a la pregunta y los logs de errores, como texto plano (que en el editor les puedes dar formato fácilmente)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con el integer.parse int capture el id

```
<%PublicacionMysqlDao pdao = new PublicacionMysqlDao();

pdao.darLikes(2, user.getId(),Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
response.sendRedirect("muro.jsp");
%>
```